# I dont see the race condition here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

This is the example code from a book:

```
#include <exception>
struct empty_stack: std::exception
{
    const char* what() const throw();
};

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_stack
{
    private:
        std::stack<T> data;
        mutable std::mutex m;

    public:
        threadsafe_stack(){}
        threadsafe_stack(const threadsafe_stack& other)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
            data=other.data;
        }

        threadsafe_stack& operator=(const threadsafe_stack&) = delete;

        void push(T new_value)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            data.push(std::move(new_value));
        }

        std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
            std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data.top())));
            data.pop();
            return res;
        }

        void pop(T& value)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
            value=std::move(data.top());
            data.pop();
        }

        bool empty() const
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            return data.empty();
        }
};
```

It says:

> there's a potential for a race condition between empty() and either of
>   the pop() functions, but because the code explicitly checks for the
>   contained stack being empty while holding the lock in pop() this race
>   condition isnt problematic

How can this be a race condition if they are both done whilst the "global" mutex is locked?

Comment: Probably just a poorly written book?

Comment: Think about what could happen if someone using the class wrote e.g. `while (!stack.empty()) stack.pop();` in multiple threads.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so you're saying those two operations need to be done within the same lock? The API doesn't seem good- too much is exposed.

Comment: Exactly, and no there's no nice way of doing it except exposing the mutex which is less than desirable. However, you could add a new function `pop_all` taking a predicate as argument, and the `pop_all` function does the looping and popping calling the predicate with each popped item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The race condition is in the client code:

```
threadsafe_stack<int> st;
...
if (!st.empty()) {
   int value = st.pop();    // Kaboom
   //...
}
```

Or in other words, another thread could have popped the stack in between the empty() and the pop() method calls.  This is in general why fine-grained locking doesn't work and needs to be taken care of by the client programmer.  The person least likely to get it right.

You should replace pop() with trypop() to make it threadsafe.

Comment: Hi @Hans Passant, what would happen if LITERALLY a variable is updated by one thread and another thread reads it EXACTLY AT THE SAME TIME (Considering there is no synchronization)? I know maybe this is not the right question but it has some relation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the code you presented. It looks misleading to me.

First off, a concurrent data structure doesn't have a "size" or "emptiness". There is no observable property like that on which you can act. A function that always returned the value true would be as useful as your "empty" function.

The only sensible thing you can do with a concurrent data structure is to *try* to get data from it. Then you either succeed or fail, and you deal with that. It's not an exceptional condition for your container to be empty. The way your code is written, *there's no way for the user to guarantee that there isn't an exception!* That's not right.

Finally, the shared pointer seems pointless. Your container has a unique consumer the way it's designed, so the interface should do just that. It's up to the user if she wants to create a shared pointer, that has nothing to do with you.

So, all in all, I recommend the following interface:

```
void push(T const & x)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    data.push(x);
}

void push(T && x)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    data.push(std::move(x));
}

bool pop(std::unique_ptr<T> & dst)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

    if (data.empty()) { return false; }

    dst.reset(::new T(std::move(data.top()));
    data.pop();
    return true;
}
```

That's it, nothing else should be part of the public interface (except perhaps an `emplace`-like push function). The details of the `pop` function are up to you; the unique pointer allows you to have non-default-constructible values. You could also use the value of `dst` as the signal whether an element was extracted successfully and do away with the `bool`.

Comment: I think its because the example I gave is part of a book which is walking-through bad design decisions too- it wasnt saying "this is the best", but i really like your answer.

Comment: Their next design uses a condition variable so that if you call pop() and nothing is there, it will wait....

Comment: Why does your first push() accept a const T object but your second push() (for rvalues) a non-const T object? Because std::move() will cause the move constructor/assignment operator to change its data members for the move?